# What does a bucked honeycomb lattice mean?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body, graphene

I was going through some literature where they have mention about bucked honeycomb lattice, but I was unable to understand about the bucked honeycomb term.

Comment: Which literature?

Answer (score 2):

One reason might be that the term is not "bucked" but it is "buckled". If you search for "buckled honeycomb lattice" you would find a lot of information.

Basically, the difference between an ordinary and buckled honeycomb structure is that the ordinary honeycomb structure is flat, or planar. One good example would be to compare benzene molecule to cyclohexane (images are from wikipedia). While benzene is flat cyclohexane is buckled.

Benzene (flat geometry, carbon is sp<sup>2</sup> hybridized)
[image]

Cyclohexane (buckled geometry, carbon is sp<sup>3</sup> hybridized)
[image]